# removeclass() from showcomments after click - from all similar classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".showcomments", function() {

alert("ok");

var element = $(this);
var id = element.attr("data-postid");

$(element).removeClass('showcomments'); //remove class after click to avoid double call to this function

});
```

and html:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="showcomments" data-postid="'1'">1</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="showcomments" data-postid="'2'">2</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="showcomments" data-postid="'3'">3</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="showcomments" data-postid="'1'">1</a>
```

when user click on 2, for exemple, it will remove class showcomments from this class and user will not be able to click on 2 anymore.

The problem is when user click on 1 (first or second link), I'd like to remove showcomments class from all 1 links (data-postid) in the page. I dont't want user to be able to click on any 1 again. Any ideas how to remove class from any 1 in the page?

https://jsfiddle.net/LnLkkvpk/

Answer (score 5):

You can probably just get all the elements with the showcomments class, then use an attribute filter on their data-postid attribute:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".showcomments", function() {
    var postid = $(this).attr("data-postid");
    $('.showcomments[data-postid="' + postid + '"]')
        .removeClass( "showcomments" );
});
```